# RSpec: Why do I have Methoderror: undefined method but this Howto not?

Tags: selenium, rspec

Since [the answer for my last question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935723/rspec-cant-verify-there-are-more-than-5-btns-on-search-result-page) we think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244041/ruby-selenium-web-driver-how-to-count-child-element-nodes-of-a-specific-node) could help me to write a test which loops through a range of Elements using RSpec.

But realy I dont see/understand WHY following code is not working in my 'spec'

Given i write in test

```
source = @driver.page_source
puts source
row = source.find_elements(:xpath => "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").length
puts row
```

Then it hits this error

```
Failure/Error: row = source.find_elements(:xpath => "//a[contains(text(),'Details')]").length

NoMethodError:
undefined method `find_elements' for #<String:0x00000003fcccd8>
```

that can not be?

Answer (score 0):

When you did `source = @driver.page_source` so now `source` have page source in string (String object).

`find_elements` works with `Selenium::WebDriver` object. That is your `@driver`(i suppose)

So just you have to do `@driver.find_elements(...)` and it will work.